# why the weight of a 8-bit quantized LLM (using GPTQ) is float 16

Tags: large-language-model, quantization, 8-bit

I know that quantization use int8 to reduce the usage of memory
But when I print the weight, it is float16
so how come quantization helps accelerate? do they convert float to int only when doing matrix multiplication and then convert them back to float?

here is my code

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline, AutoConfig

model_name_or_path = "TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-Chat-GPTQ"
# To use a different branch, change revision
# For example: revision="gptq-4bit-64g-actorder_True"
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, device_map="auto",
                                             trust_remote_code=False,
                                             revision="main")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, use_fast=True)
# check if model is quantized

# print a weight

prompt = "Tell me about AI"
prompt_template= prompt



print("\n\n*** Generate:")

input_ids = tokenizer(prompt_template, return_tensors='pt').input_ids.cuda(1)

print(model.lm_head.weight)
```

and here is the output

```
*** Generate:
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.0036,  0.0027, -0.0074,  ...,  0.0039, -0.0084,  0.0065],
        [-0.0311,  0.0449, -0.0029,  ..., -0.0228,  0.0147,  0.0320],
        [-0.0125,  0.0014,  0.0188,  ..., -0.0264,  0.0156, -0.0073],
        ...,
        [-0.0294, -0.0172, -0.0029,  ...,  0.0140, -0.0116, -0.0234],
        [ 0.0204,  0.0239,  0.0272,  ...,  0.0048, -0.0097, -0.0064],
        [ 0.0081, -0.0057,  0.0082,  ..., -0.0282, -0.0164,  0.0311]],
       device='cuda:1', dtype=torch.float16, requires_grad=True)
```